# REST API to stocktwits.com in R

Tags: r, rest, oauth-2.0, httr, stocktwits

I have been banging my head over this the whole day. I am trying to access StockTwits API (https://api.stocktwits.com/developers) from an R session. I have earlier accessed the twitter API (via `rtweet`) without hassles.

I have created an app and got the client id and key (the below are just examples).

```
app_name = "some.name";
consumer_key = "my_client_id";
consumer_secret = "my_client_key";
uri = "http://iimb.ac.in" # this is my institute's homepage. It doesn't allow locahost OR 127.0.0.1
scope = "read,watch_lists,publish_messages,publish_watch_lists,direct_messages,follow_users,follow_stocks";
base_url = "https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth"; # see https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api
```

The procedure is to create an oauth2.0 app and endpoint. Then call `oauth2.0_token`.

```
oa = httr::oauth_app(app_name, key = consumer_key, secret = consumer_secret, redirect_uri = uri);

oe = httr::oauth_endpoint("stocktwits", "authorize", "token", base_url = base_url);

mytoken = httr::oauth2.0_token(oe, oa, user_params = list(resource = base_url), use_oob = F); # use_oob = T doesn't work.
```

After firing the above, it takes me to the browser for sign-in. I sign-in and it asks me to connect. After that, I am taken back to my URI plus a code, i.e. https://www.iimb.ac.in/?code=295ea3114c3d8680a0ed295d52313d7092dd90ae&state=j9jXzEqri1

Is the code my access token or something else? The `oauth2.0_token()` call keeps waiting for the code since the callback is not localhost. I didn't seem to get a hang of that.

I then try to access the API using the above code as access token but I am thrown "***invalid access token***" error. The format is described in https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#search-index-docs

Can someone tell me what I have missed? If required I can share my `app_name, consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` for replication.